# Windows が自動で外付け HDD にアクセスするのを止める方法

Tags: windows

Stackoverflow ではなく Server Fault や Super User が適している質問に思いますが、日本語対応していないのでこちらで質問させていただきます。

Windows10 に外付け HDD を接続し、その HDD 内のフォルダを公開することでファイルサーバとして使用しています。
ただし、アクセス頻度は少なく HDD の音がうるさいので、非使用時は節電も兼ねて HDD の電源を落とすようにしています。
この電源管理は手動ではなく Windows によるもので、しばらくアクセスが無いと自動で HDD の電源が落ちて、アクセスすると電源が入るようになっています。

しかし、アクセスしていないのに HDD の回転が始まることが頻繁にあります。
セキュリティソフトによるものかと思い、 HDD のアクセスがあったタイミングでセキュリティソフトのスキャンログを見ましたがスキャンは行われていないようでした。
その他、自動でファイルにアクセスするようなソフトは入れていません。
HDD にアクセスがあった直後にリソースモニターでアクセスされたファイルを見ると、 `$Mft` や `$LogFile` というシステムファイルらしきもので、アクセスしたプロセスは System でした。
Windows OS 自身によるアクセスかと思うのですが、これを防ぐ方法はないでしょうか？
ユーザがアクセスしない限り外付け HDD へのアクセスは行わず電源も入れないようにしたいです。

Comment: あとお約束なんだけど Windows 10 はサーバー OS としての利用が認められていないので注意。やっていいことは EULA にて制約されています。一応確認のほどを。

Comment: @774RR  さん Windows 10 EULAの2.d.(iii)で「ファイルサービス」は最大20台まで接続することを許可しているため、所謂ファイルサーバーとしての利用は20台までなら問題ないはずです。 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/OEM/Windows/10/Useterms_OEM_Windows_10_Japanese.htm

Answer (score 2):

セキュリティソフトの勝手スキャンや Windows による自動インデックス生成などなど、勝手にアクセスする要因は複数個あります。一つ停止し忘れただけでも目的は達せられないし、今後の Windows/セキュリティソフトのバージョンアップで項目が増えたり変わったりすることは容易に予想されますので、やるだけ無駄というのが正直な感想です。

電源ユニットは入れっぱなしなんですよね？　電源ユニットや電源アダプタからの音が気にならないのであればハードディスクから SSD に変えちゃいましょう。勝手に電源入ったり切れたりしても、ほぼ無音です。コストも下がってきてますし。

# 無響室に測定器としてノートPCを持ち込むと SSD 上の DCDC コンバータからコイル鳴きが聞こえたことはあります

Comment: 以前は Linux サーバでやっていてその頃はそういったことはなくすごく快適だったのですが、諸事情で Windows の機能が必要で Windows に切り替えてからうるさくて困ってるのでどうにかしたいという状態なんです。
外付けデバイスのアクセスの制御すら簡単にできないとなると Windows OS はやめたほうがいいのですかね・・・

うるさいのは HDD なので SSD 化は検討しましたが容量が大きいので、同等の SSD となると結構高くなります。
収入があるサービスとしてのサーバーではないので、それに何万円もかけるのは難しいです。

Comment: お金だけで根本原因が解決するならそのほうが手早いし安全安心だし結局は安くつく、というのはオイラの体験というか経験というか。まああとはあなたの判断次第っス。

Answer (score 0):

- あくまで OS の制御でなんとかするという方向であれば、以下ページのように「スリープを防ぐ方法」を参考に、逆の事をするのも一つの案です。

  [外付けHDDの電源が切れてスリープになるのを防ぐ方法【Windows10】](https://pg-happy.jp/usb-hdd-power-option.html)

  あまりアグレッシブに停止してしまうようだと、今度は必要なアクセス時に時間がかかりそうな印象ではあります。
- 使用中の外付けHDDに関する情報が質問に含まれていませんが、最近の製品であれば大抵は外付けHDD側に「省電力モード (一定時間後にスリープさせる機能)」が備わっているので、それらへの乗り換えを検討してみる。
- 音の原因を突き止めて改善しましょう。例えば振動であるなら、設置場所を変えたり防振ゴムを敷くだけで改善するかもしれません。

Comment: その Windows の設定が有効なので現状でもスリープモードにはなります。
しかし、一日に何度も Windows が自動で HDD にアクセスするのでスリープモードが解除されて起動してしまいます。
外付け HDD 側の機能を利用してもアクセスがあればスリープが解除されるのは同じなので、解決にはいたりません。
物理的なトグルスイッチタイプのものだと Windows から HDD は認識されなくなり、起動はしないでしょうが、使用時に ON に切り替えるために外付け HDD の近くにいないといけなくなるので使えません。
音は性能が高めで回転数の多い HDD によくある感じの振動や駆動音?で、一応静音性をうたっているケースに入れて買えてみましたが改善していません。